# extract subset of data from multiindex dataframe and calculate difference of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where in the first row I have multiple entries but the 2nd row has repeating columns.

```
               A                    B                 C
Date           open    r    close   open    r  close  open    r   close      
2000-07-03     19.7    5    17.1    66.26   4  6.22   23.26.  1   9.9
2000-07-05     49.8    2    8.3     78.81   6  4.34   39.81   5   5.1
2000-07-15     89.5    3    4.1     43.45   7  2.45   29.3    8   1.2
2000-08-13     74.7    6    7.4     34.26   8  6.4    72.26   9   5.4
2000-08-25     39.84   1    8.4     95.43   3  4.3    69.81.  0   5.2
2000-08-28     61.8    4    4.2     43.81   1  2.2    129.81  6   1.3
2000-09-11     82.79   7    7.4     66.26   1  6.5    72.25   6   5.6
2000-09-16     64.8    8    8.7     73.45   5  4.7    69.45   4   5.4
2000-09-22     58.5    9    3.3     13.81   8  2.9    777.8   8   1.4
```

I want to extract data for 7th month of 2000 and find out which is the lowest (Open - Close) from A or B  or C?

MY PLAN:

```
s=data.stack(level=0)
values = s[s.index.get_level_values(1)]['open', 'close'].reset_index()
values['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(values['Date'])
start_date = 2000-07-01
end_date = 2000-08-01
mask = (data['date'] > start_date) & (data['date'] <= end_date)
df = data.loc[mask]
df['Val_Diff'] = df['open'] - df['close']
print(df['Val_Diff'].max())
```

I get the error

```
KeyError: "None of [Index are in the [columns]"
```

why is multiindex a problem for this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's caused by the unnamed columns in the index when the stack deforms vertically.
Process flow:

1. Flatten the column names of multi-indexes.
2. Transform from horizontal to vertical using the wide_to_long function
3. Convert the date sequence to 'Datetime' format for conditional extraction.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import datetime

data = '''
Date open r close open r close open r close  
2000-07-03 19.7 5 17.1 66.26 4 6.22 23.26 1 9.9
2000-07-05 49.8 2 8.3 78.81 6 4.34 39.81 5 5.1
2000-07-15 89.5 3 4.1 43.45 7 2.45 29.3 8 1.2
2000-08-13 74.7 6 7.4 34.26 8 6.4 72.26 9 5.4
2000-08-25 39.84 1 8.4 95.43 3 4.3 69.81 0 5.2
2000-08-28 61.8 4 4.2 43.81 1 2.2 129.81 6 1.3
2000-09-11 82.79 7 7.4 66.26 1 6.5 72.25 6 5.6
2000-09-16 64.8 8 8.7 73.45 5 4.7 69.45 4 5.4
2000-09-22 58.5 9 3.3 13.81 8 2.9 777.8 8 1.4
'''

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'], ['Date','open','r','close','open','r','close','open','r','close']])
data.columns = idx
new_cols = [k[1]+'_'+k[0] for k in data.columns[1:]]
new_cols.insert(0, 'Date')
data.columns = new_cols
data = pd.wide_to_long(data,['open','r','close'], i='Date', j='item', sep='_', suffix='\\w+')
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
start_date = datetime.datetime(2000,7,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2000,8,1)
mask = (data.Date > start_date) & (data.Date <= end_date)
data = data.loc[mask]
data
    Date    item    open    r   close
0   2000-07-03  A   19.70   5   17.10
1   2000-07-05  A   49.80   2   8.30
2   2000-07-15  A   89.50   3   4.10
9   2000-07-03  B   66.26   4   6.22
10  2000-07-05  B   78.81   6   4.34
11  2000-07-15  B   43.45   7   2.45
18  2000-07-03  C   23.26   1   9.90
19  2000-07-05  C   39.81   5   5.10
20  2000-07-15  C   29.30   8   1.20

data['Val_Diff'] = data['open'] - data['close']
print(data['Val_Diff'].max()) 
85.4
```